# NSlocalized string does not appear on uialert view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I am making an app in which i want to show uialert view. i am giving NSLocalized string to this uialertview.But my Nslocalized string does not appear on uialertview only empty alert view appear. i am unable to understaand what is the problem below is my code:

```
if(!self.transporterCompanyName_.text || [self.transporterCompanyName_.text isEqualToString:@""] || !self.transporterLastName_.text || [self.transporterLastName_.text isEqualToString:@""] || !self.transporterFirstName_.text || [self.transporterFirstName_.text isEqualToString:@""] || !self.transporterEmail_.text || [self.transporterEmail_.text isEqualToString:@""] || !self.transporterTelNo_.text || [self.transporterTelNo_.text isEqualToString:@""] || !self.transporterUserName_.text || [self.transporterUserName_.text isEqualToString:@""] || !self.transporterPassword_.text || [self.transporterPassword_.text isEqualToString:@""] || !self.transporterConfirmPassword_.text || [self.transporterConfirmPassword_.text isEqualToString:@""]){

        [FBMessageHandler displayAlertMessageWithOkButton:NSLocalizedString(@"All text fields are mandatory. Please fill the complete form and then submit!", @"incomplete reg form") backgroundImage:nil tag:0 andDelegate:self addInQueue:NO andParentViewController:self];

        return;
    }
```

here is my FbMessageHandler

```
+ (void)displayAlertMessageWithOkButton:(NSString *)message backgroundImage:(NSString*)bImage
                                  tag:(int)tagValue
                            andDelegate:(id)delegate addInQueue:(BOOL)queue andParentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    FBAlertViewController *alert = [[FBAlertViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FBAlertWithOkOption" andMessage:message backgroundImage:bImage tag:tagValue andDelegate:delegate addInQueue:queue buttonText:nil];
    [viewController addChildViewController:alert];
    [viewController.view addSubview:alert.view];
    [alert didMoveToParentViewController:viewController];
    alert = nil;
}
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: your alert view is fine, check that "message" is comes at empty or null..

Comment: Message is not coming null or empty

Comment: `NSLog` your localizedstring.

Comment: Can you show us the corresponding strings file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this

```
 [FBMessageHandler displayAlertMessageWithOkButton:NSLocalizedString(@"All text fields are mandatory. Please fill the complete form and then submit!", @"incomplete reg form") backgroundImage:nil tag:0 andDelegate:self addInQueue:NO andParentViewController:self];
```

into

```
    [FBMessageHandler displayAlertMessageWithOkButton:NSLocalizedString(@"All text fields are mandatory. Please fill the complete form and then submit!, incomplete reg form") backgroundImage:nil tag:0 andDelegate:self addInQueue:NO andParentViewController:self];
```

**choice no 2**

```
    NSString *msgstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"All text fields are mandatory. Please fill the complete form and then submit!,incomplete reg form"];


   [FBMessageHandler displayAlertMessageWithOkButton:msgstr backgroundImage:nil tag:0 andDelegate:self addInQueue:NO andParentViewController:self];
```